# Typesetting superscripts and subscripts with system fonts in Xelatex

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts, xltxtra

My document is required to be typeset in a font called DINPro.  I need to use both subscripts and  superscripts within the text.  I would like to  use \textsubscript and \textsuperscript, howerver \textsuperscript doesn't change scaling or position of affected text.  \textsubscript changes position properly but does not scale.

As an alternative I have tried using math mode like BASE$_{SUBSCRIPT}$. It scales and positions nicely, but it uses  roman/italic.  Is there any way to use either of these methods with my  font to get properly scaled and  positioned sub/superscripts in my required font?
MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=NoCommon, SizeFeatures = {Size=12}}
\newfontfamily\BodyFont{DINPro-Light}[SizeFeatures = {Size=11}] 
\begin{document}
\begin{tt}
{\bf Testing textsubscript and text superscript with tt font:} \newline
BASE\textsuperscript{SUPERSCRIPT} \newline
BASE\textsubscript{SUBSCRIPT} \newline
Note that the sub/superscript is smaller than the base and centered respectively with  the lower and upper edges of the base. \newline
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\par
\end{tt}

\begin{BodyFont}
{\bf Testing textsubscript and text superscript with DINPro-Light, Size 11, downloaded from internet:} \newline
BASE\textsuperscript{SUPERSCRIPT} \newline
BASE\textsubscript{SUBSCRIPT} \newline
1)Boldface reverts to roman font. \newline2)DINPro font  textsuperscript doesn't work at all. \newline  3)textsubscript works but the subscript font size is the same as the base. \newline Question:  Is this an issue  with the font I used?  DINPro is the required font for my document so I need to figure out how to make it work.\newline
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\par

{\bf Alternative question: Testing math mode subscript  andsuperscript with DINPro-Light, Size 11, downloaded from internet:} \newline
BASE$^{SUPERSCRIPT}$ \newline
BASE$_{SUBSCRIPT}$ \newline
 This looks much better, however the math mode font is roman and italic.  Is there any way to prevent transiton  roman and italic in math mode?
\end{BodyFont}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! As a workaround, try `\textsubscript{\scriptsize …}` and similarly for the superscript.

Comment: try without the xltxtra package (which load the realscript package, and if your font doesn't have them it can harm).

Comment: When I comment out \usepackage{xltxtra}, the \textsuperscript  and \textsubscript  both position correctly relative to the base but they still do not scale to a smaller size.

Comment: remove the `SizeFeatures` settings.

Comment: @Bernard, I think \scriptsize is not working for me because I am explicitly  defining the size in the \newfontfamily definitions. But it leads me to a work around.  I just use \newfontfamily to dfine a 7pt version of DINPro called ScriptFont.  Then  the sub/superscritp lines become `BASE\textsubscript{{\ScriptFont SUBSCRIPT}}\newline`.  It doesn't scale automatically, but it looks okay with the range of font sizes I will use and I can change the size globally from the preamble if I need to.

Comment: No your use of Sizefeature is nonsense, you don't understand the purpose of the option. Simply remove it.

Comment: Ulrike, I'm using SizeFeature because the template I'm working from specifies nine different font sizes  for reasons that I do not control.  In the MWE I can comment out the three instances of SizeFeatures,  and the \textsubscript{} format ends up looking great, however, the font size is now relative to the article  document class default and I need to use \huge \tiny \....  I loose my hook to directly specify the size as required.